# How do I change PCap.Net packet data?

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I have a (production) WireShark capture file that I need to 'replay' over my (debug) network. I can read and interpret the packets, but I need to tweak a few details before the packets can be sent, like source IP addresses and ports.

The problem, however, is that all data in the PcapDotNet.Packets.Packet is read-only. It just has setters.
So like setting for instance the Ethernet.IpV4.Source will not work.

```
IpV4Address.TryParse("192.168.1.10", out var newAddress); // for demo sake.
packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Source = newAddress; // Won't work
```

Is there a simple way to avoid building a new packet from scratch, or is that the only way to create a slightly different packet?

Comment: Maybe you can do it through reflection, but it depends on how it is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the packet inplace, you should just create a new one based on the old one.

You can use `ExtractLayer()` on each layer you want to keep from the old packet, and then change the layer properties if necessary.

In this case, you can do:

```
IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
ipV4Layer.Source = newAddress;

Packet newPacket = PacketBuild.Build(DateTime.Now, packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer(), ipV4Layer, packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload.ExtractLayer());
```

You probably also want to reset the IPv4 checksum, so you should do:

```
ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
```

And you might need to something similar to the UDP or TCP layers on top of the IPv4 layer, in case you have them.